# How to properly upload 3D content to YouTube in high definition?

Tags: youtube, 3d

[TrackMania Nations Forever](http://trackmaniaforever.com/) allows users to export 3D videos of replays and I thought I would try my hand at uploading it to YouTube. I rendered the video at 1920x1080 for each camera, resulting in a video that is 3840x1080. I uploaded the video and clicked "advanced settings." I set the 3D options accordingly:

[image]

After the upload completed, I went to view the video ([link here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LERkxsSYKxw)) and ran into some problems:

- Unlike other 3D videos on YouTube, my video does not display the [3d](/questions/tagged/3d) tag.

  [image]
- When watching the video, I have a button in the player labeled "3D":

  [image]

  "Change 3D viewing mode" just reloads the page and has no effect, and "turn on converted 3D" has absolutely no effect whatsoever.

What did I do wrong? Other 3D videos on YouTube do not have this problem. They offer side-by-side view, z-anaglyph mode, etc.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Your video]

Your video has the 3D and 4K tags when I searched it. And does have the option for anaglyph and 2D.
I looked at other videos and those are the only two that are displayed (I checked using Chrome as well, not just Edge).  I don't see "side by side"

Comment: Just noticed how long ago this question was XD